# Compare head of the local branch with a commit from the remote branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to compare the current state of my local branch "master" with a certain commit (hash "8029345") from the "origin/master" with "--name-status".

so far i have:

```
git diff --name-status master .. origin/master
```

how do i specify a certain commit in origin/master? Should be trivial, but i can't find a proper way. I went through the [git-diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) but don't see how to do it.

**Background of the issue**: after merging origin/master to master I think i forgot to "git add" certain new files. Now, after i advanced my local branch quite a lot and also fetched new content of the origin branch i would really like to fix this issue and add the files i did not add while merging.

**UPDATE**:
i am not sure if i understand diff correctly, but it seems this:

```
git diff --name-status d874367 8029345
                       ^sha-loc ^sha on remote branch (just before merging)
```

does not show me which files are untracked in the local DVCS as compared to the remote one...

Comment: `origin/master` simply names a commit (try `git rev-parse origin/master`, you'll see what I mean).  You can name any other commit in any of the ways documented in [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), e.g., raw SHA-1, or `origin/master~5`, or whatever.

Comment: Re update: diff-ing commits diffs their trees, and their trees by definition do not contain untracked files.  However, if tree A is missing file `only-in-B` that tree B has, the `--name-status` of a diff from A to B will show file `only-in-B` as "added".

Comment: @torek. Thank you for the explanation, i think the problem is fully resolved now.